# How to Use Angular2 app QuickStart Demo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, angular, web-applications

Trying out sample from this link https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html
added and created all files with exact structure, installed dependancies , when i run this example by opening index.html file from src folder , but its stuck with "loading...." message in browser.
I am trying this out on server running Cent OS7 with Apache 2 the entire app folder is inside html folder under www.
Is there anything else I need to configure ? Note I am not using nom lite server I know its for local testing. I am trying this under apache.
Any help will be appreciated.

here is the source https://github.com/vdharankar/quickstart_aj

Comment: Drop your app into plunker and share it with us.

Comment: Its exactly same as the code available on the quickstart link

Comment: @Kinduser check the GitHub link for code please

Comment: Does the quickstart work using the CLI tools or tsc and the lite-server they recommend locally?  Are you building a bundle and deploying that?

Comment: @shaunhusain and a novice angular user , just starting so I have no idea about that , i just created files the way they told and put everything under html dir, however i have installed all the modules there

Comment: Ah okay also I was a little off here you're looking at the native JS versions of the quickstart I've only used the TypeScript version which requires compiling before you serve up the files, the raw JS ones should be fine as is.  Do you see any errors in the console is the site somewhere we can all take a look?

Comment: @shaunhusain no error it just says "Loading..." nothing else

Comment: @vishaldharankar ah the silent failure.... my worst enemy :).  Next things to check are in the network panel see that the sources you expect are loading so should see if your main.js (refresh the page with the network panel open) if you see main.js click on it and check the response details of the main.js to see it has your code.  If so can go over to the sources panel and add a breakpoint in the main.js to see if it fires the bootstrap.

Comment: @shaunhusain this entire thing is on server no network or source panel here to debug

Comment: **what does your JavaScript console say?**

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy where to check ?

Comment: if you are using chrome, check this article. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ usually it can be opened with `F12` or `ctrl+shift+j`.

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy ok now i see several errors related to .js files not found, looks likes its not able to load modules , i wonder if this is to do with some path setting or apache config ?

Comment: OK everyone thanks for your support sorted this by placing node_modules inside src, by this way it was able to find the modules on apache on server and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this by moving the node_modules folder inside src directory on server and now apache was able to serve those .js files to browser without issue.